# Getting the name of a TypeScript class at compile time

Tags: typescript, class, typescript-generics

I would like to define a type that extracts the name of a class (its `name` property) at compile time, as a string literal.

```
class Class {}

// I would like this to compile... (because Class.name === "Class")
const thisShouldCompile: ExtractName<Class> = "Class";

// ...and this to be a compilation error (because Class.name !== "Foo")
const thisShouldFail: ExtractName<Class> = "Foo";
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If not, why not?

This is what I have tried:

```
type ExtractName1<C extends Function> = C["name"];
type Broken1 = ExtractName1<Class>; 
//                          ^^^^^ Type 'Class' does not satisfy the constraint 'Function'.
//                                Type 'Class' is missing the following properties from type 'Function': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.

type ExtractName2<C extends Pick<Function, 'name'>> = C["name"];
type Broken2 = ExtractName2<Class>;
//                          ^^^^^ Type 'Class' does not satisfy the constraint 'Pick<Function, "name">'.
//                                Property 'name' is missing in type 'Class' but required in type 'Pick<Function, "name">'.

type ExtractName3<C extends {name: string}> = C["name"];
type Broken3 = ExtractName3<Class>;
//                          ^^^^^ Type 'Class' does not satisfy the constraint '{ name: string; }'.
//                                Property 'name' is missing in type 'Class' but required in type '{ name: string; }'.
```

Comment: Note that `Class` represents the type of an instance of `Class` which does not have a `name` property. To get the type of the constructor itself, use `typeof Class`. But you will see that `type Name = typeof Class["name"]` is just of type `string`, so it is still not possible to get the name of a class as a string literal in any way.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with generic types?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do this but I'm waiting for this feature as well. There is a long discussion about it on the typescript gh page if you want to check it out, but for some reason, the conversation was limited to collaborators :(

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579

Comment: "_but for some reason, the conversation was limited to collaborators_" - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579#issuecomment-505262490